# delete value from input

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i delete input value, when I uncheck checkbox?

```
 <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="checkBox"></mat-checkbox>
 <input formControlName="input" type="text"/>
```

So i want to delete value from typscript.How can i do it?

I try this :

```
private clearInput(): void {
    if (this.formGroup.controls.checkBox.value === false) {
      this.formGroup.controls.input.setValue(null);
    }
  }
```

but this is not working.

Comment: I guess you are talking about `angular` rather `angularjs`. For you question, you can add `(change)="clearInput()" `  and  do whatever you want to do inside`clearInput` method.

Comment: It's ookay, but how?

Comment: `<mat-checkbox color="primary" (change)="clearInput()"  formControlName="checkBox"></mat-checkbox>` you can try like this. Is that your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be the following:

- Modify your html to:

```html
<mat-checkbox 
  color="primary" 
  formControlName="checkBox"
  (change)="clearInput($event, inputId)">
</mat-checkbox>
<input #inputId formControlName="input" type="text"/>
```

The `change` event emitter will notify you when the checkbox value has changed.

When the value of the checkbox changes, it will call the `clearInput` method.

The 1º argument is the event itself, `$event`, which is of the type `MatCheckboxChange`, according to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api).

The 2º argument is the reference to the `<input>`.

- Modify the ts to:

```
clearInput(checkboxChange: MatCheckboxChange, input: HTMLInputElement): void {
  if (!checkboxChange.checked) { input.value = '' }
}
```

This will clear your input field only if the checkbox is changed to not selected.